# Python Appium InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'partial link text' is not supported for this session

Tags: python, android, appium

I am doing Native App test automation using Appium in python.
I want to find element that include specific string using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`
but it doesn't work.

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

class WebDriverSetup(unittest.TestCase):

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
   desired_cap = {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:decviceName": "ce0516057594590c04",
    "appium:appPackage": "com.lotte",
    "appium:appActivity": "com.lotte.on.splash.LotteSplashActivity"
   }

   capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_cap)
   cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',options=capabilities_options)

  def test_case_1(self):
    self.driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,value='abcd')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testcase = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(WebDriverSetup)
    unittest.main(testcase)`
```

This is error message

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Locator Strategy 'partial link text' is not supported for this session; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#invalid-selector-exception
> Stacktrace:
> InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'partial link text' is not supported for this session

I reinstalled appium-python_client in pycharm.